# how to hide bottom bar from in a screen inside stackNavigator react-navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have simple `createBottomTabNavigator` and one of it's tabs is `createStackNavigator` and inside this `stack` I have one screen which I want it to over lap the tab bar. I tried use `tabBarVisible: false` on this screen but no luck there.

Code:

```
const BookingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Commutes: {
    screen: Commutes,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Commutes",
      header: null,
    }
  },
  Tickets: {
    screen: Tickets,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Tickets",
      header: null,
      tabBarVisible: false
    }
  }
});

export const MainNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Current: {
    screen: Current,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Current",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <IconIO name="ios-bus" size={scale(20)} color={tintColor} />
      )
    }
  },
  BookingsStack: {
    screen: BookingsStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Commutes",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <IconSL name="layers" size={scale(20)} color={tintColor} />
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As given in the navigation document:

If we want to hide the tab bar when we navigate from the feed home to a details screen without shuffling navigators, we cannot set the `tabBarVisible: false` configuration in `navigationOptions` on `DetailsScreen`, because those options will only apply to the `FeedStack`. Instead, we can do the following:

```
 const FeedStack = createStackNavigator({   FeedHome: FeedScreen,  
     Details: DetailsScreen, });

     FeedStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {   let
    tabBarVisible = true;   if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
         tabBarVisible = false;   }

       return {
         tabBarVisible,
   }; };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the `react-navigation` docs - the implementation look like this:

```
const ChildMainNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Current: {
    screen: Current,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Current",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <IconIO name="ios-bus" size={scale(20)} color={tintColor} />
      )
    }
  },
  Commutes: {
    screen: Commutes,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Commutes",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <IconSL name="layers" size={scale(20)} color={tintColor} />
      )
    }
  }
}

export const MainNav = createStackNavigator({
  ChildMainNav: {
    screen: ChildMainNav,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },

  // overlap screens
  Tickets: {
    screen: Tickets,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Tickets",
      header: null,
      tabBarVisible: false
    }
  }
});
```

The idea is to add the Tab navigator into Stack navigator and add in this stack any other screens you want to have different `navigationOptions` to overlap the ones in your Tab.

[Link to docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html) under:

> A tab navigator contains a stack and you want to hide the tab bar on specific screens